# Python 3.4.3 and PySqlite3 not Inserting content on Table

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

Actually I'm working on a Python and SQLite based url Shortener that will allow people to shorten their urls. But I'm in a trouble, so thats why I'm here hehe! So, my code is not inserting a thing into the database!

This is the connection and insertion code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(DBSource)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO URLStorage VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')".format(urlFinal, urlprocessar, datetime.datetime.now())
#return(query)
cursor.execute(query)
```

If you want to take a look at the full source code to see if I mess something else, this is the link for it: https://github.com/vmesel/WP-A.CO

Comment: Why aren't you using the `sqlite3` module?

Comment: I'm using it! Im just using it as: import sqlite3 as sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want either a commit or close after you execute the query:

```
connection.commit()
```

or

```
connection.close()
```